# Electron app crashes on print ubuntu 20.04 Linux

Tags: electron

It's been a week I am struggling with this problem. I've searched throughout the web and found many answers but none of them worked for me and also most of the topics relating to this problem are unsolved in various forums as well.
Whenever my application executes the following line of code from the main process it crashes :

win.webContents.print();

Following is the crash report:

'''
[image: Crash Report]

```
I've tried the option:
         win.webContents.print({silent: true}, (success, error) => {
          if(success) {
            console.log("Printed...");
          }else {
            console.log(error);
          }
      });
```

'''
No matter what I do, I get the same crash report.
Furthermore, If I print from the console of the browser window, the same crash occurs,

'''
[image: Printing from the console of browser window]

With the same error as shown below :

[image: Crash Report 2]
'''

I am very close to the deadline of a project in which I have to integrate a printing facility to the POS thermal receipt printer, and can not find any solutions.

Also, I've used other libraries like [electron-pos-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pos-printer), But internally, it uses the same concept and codes for printing, and thus, this way also failed.

It's really frustrating... Need help !!!